# Need help in understanding the error. I have tried from a similar post

Tags: python-3.x

For context please see this:
[Whats wrong with the code? It result in RE in google Kickstart 2020 Round A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63533699/whats-wrong-with-the-code-it-result-in-re-in-google-kickstart-2020-round-a/63994305?noredirect=1#comment113161873_63994305)

My attempt:
https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ffc7/00000000001d3f56

I have written a piece of code for the exact same problem but kick start says wrong answer and test skipped.

```
T = int(input())
for k in range(1, T+1):
    X = 0
    _, B = map(int,input().split())
    A = list(map(int,input().split(' ')))
    for i in A:
        if B >= i:
            X+=1
            B-=i
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(k,X))
```

I need help in understanding why this wouldn't work.

Comment: I think your issue is that you always try to buy the houses in order, but one of the examples says that you can buy the "1st and 3rd houses". You may wish to try a recursive approach.

Comment: @rassar Thanks I forgot to sort the list.

Comment: You shouldn't put the answer in the edit, but instead post it as an answer to this question and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

FOUND THE PROBLEM AND SOLVED IT. Thanks to @rassar

```
T = int(input())
for k in range(1, T+1):
    X = 0
    _, B = map(int,input().split())
    A = sorted(list(map(int,input().split(' '))))
    for i in A:
        if B >= i:
            X+=1
            B-=i
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(k,X))
```